# How to add a function to a google maps info window

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have a function that produces a variable at the end called TotalMiles. I need to add it to my content window at the end of my code. However, I keep receiving an error saying the variable is undefined. How can I access my TotalMiles variable inside my index file for a rails application?

```
//ADD MARKERS
function addMarker(props) {
      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: props.coordinates,
        map:resultsMap
    });

        //FINDING DISTANCE IF THERE ARE COORDINATES
        if(props.coordinates) {
          var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
          if(props.State == "IN") {
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
              origins: ["6400 Brotherhood Way"],
              destinations: [props.coordinates],
              travelMode: 'DRIVING',
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
              avoidHighways: false,
              avoidTolls: false
            }, function(response, status) {
              if (status !== 'OK') {
                alert('Error was: ' + status);
              } else {
                deleteMarkers(markersArray);

                //SETTING DISTANCE AND DURATION EQUAL TO A VARIABLE
                TotalMiles = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance["text"];
                console.log(TotalMiles);
                duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration["text"];
              }
            });

          //MAKING AN INFO WINDOW WITH CONTENT
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:"Adjuster name: " + props.Adjustername + "<br/>Coverage Type: " + props.Adjustment + "<br/> Firm Name: " + props.firmName + "<br/> Phone Number: " + props.Phone + "<br/> Comments: " + props.content + "<br/> Website: " + props.Website + "<br/> Email: " + props.email + "<br/> Distance: " + TotalMiles + "  miles" + "<br/>" + props.EditContent +""
          });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getDistanceMatrix` method makes an asynchronous request. This means that your code doesn't wait for `service.getDistanceMatrix` to get results from the request before moving onto `var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:...});`.

So when that line (`var infoWindow = ...`) executes, the request still hasn't completed and retrieved the results from the web server. This in turn means that the callback function (that starts with `function(response, status) {...}`) has not been executed and so `TotalMiles` has not yet been created.

The key is to set the info window's content once you've received results from your Distance Matrix request. I changed your code to the following:

```
//ADD MARKERS
function addMarker(props) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: props.coordinates,
        map: resultsMap
    });

    //FINDING DISTANCE IF THERE ARE COORDINATES
    if (props.coordinates) {
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
        if (props.State == "IN") {

            // CREATE AN INFO WINDOW INSTANCE 
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();                

            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: ["6400 Brotherhood Way"],
                destinations: [props.coordinates],
                travelMode: 'DRIVING',
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function(response, status) {
                if (status !== 'OK') {
                    alert('Error was: ' + status);
                } else {
                    deleteMarkers(markersArray);

                    //SETTING DISTANCE AND DURATION EQUAL TO A VARIABLE
                    TotalMiles = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance["text"];
                    console.log(TotalMiles);
                    duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration["text"];

                    infoWindow.setContent("Adjuster name: " + props.Adjustername + "<br/>Coverage Type: " + props.Adjustment + "<br/> Firm Name: " + props.firmName + "<br/> Phone Number: " + props.Phone + "<br/> Comments: " + props.content + "<br/> Website: " + props.Website + "<br/> Email: " + props.email + "<br/> Distance: " + TotalMiles + "  miles" + "<br/>" + props.EditContent + "");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So happy I could cry. Thank you

Comment:  You're welcome, hopefully the explanation made sense!

Answer (score 2):

`TotalMiles` is never declared in this block of code. Before `if(props.coordinates) {` you could say `var TotalMiles = 0;`, then it would be defined even if there are no coordinates supplied. However, if `service.getDistanceMatrix` is asynchronous, `TotalMiles` will always show up as 0 since the JS will continue to execute while the AJAX is processing. In that case you'll want to create the `infoWindow` inside the response callback.